# NetSuite OAUTH1 POST request works in Postman but fails using Restsharp

Tags: c#, oauth, netsuite, restsharp

I have code to allow us to use the NetSuite REST API using OAuth 1.0. Everything works fine, except one call. When trying to do /salesorder/{id}/!transform/itemFulfillment  It fails with 401. All other calls work fine.  When I execute the same call from Postman it works fine too. What am I missing?

Here is my Code:

```
private static async Task CreateItemFulFillmentsAsync(NetSuiteJob job, int id, Item item)
{
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest($"{job.RecordUrl}/salesorder/{id}/!transform/itemFulfillment", Method.Post);
    request.AddBody(item);

    RestHelper restHelper = new RestHelper();
    RestResponse response = await restHelper.ExecuteRestRequest(request, job);
    if (response == null || !response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Failed to create the Item Fulfillment for the Sales Order: {id}.\r\n" + response.Content);
    }
}
```

And the Helper Class:

```
public async Task<RestResponse> ExecuteRestRequest(RestRequest request, NetSuiteJob job)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient(job.BaseUrl) { Authenticator = GetOAuth1Authenticator(job) };
    RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
    return response;
}

private OAuth1Authenticator GetOAuth1Authenticator(NetSuiteJob job)
{
    OAuth1Authenticator oAuth1 = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(
                                                        consumerKey: job.ConsumerKey,
                                                        consumerSecret: job.ConsumerSecret,
                                                        token: job.TokenId,
                                                        tokenSecret: job.TokenSecret,
                                                        OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha256);
    oAuth1.Realm = job.Realm;
    return oAuth1;
}
```

The results are:

> {"type":"https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2",
> "title":"Unauthorized","status":401,
> "o:errorDetails":[{"detail":"Invalid login attempt.  For more details,
> see the Login Audit Trail in the NetSuite UI at Setup > Users/Roles 
> > User Management > View Login Audit Trail.","o:errorCode":"INVALID_LOGIN"}]}

In NetSuite's Login Audit Trail, this call is logged as a failure and Role is blank, but the other calls using different action shows the Role like it should.  The working routines use the same helper class but are doing it with a different URL and Body.  I've verified the content being passed matches what I did manually in Postman too.

Comment: I ran into the same issue in the past couple days. A review of the Login Audit Trail seems to indicate the Role only gets populated for Successful requests.

Comment: If anyone does come here.  Our solution was to rewrite the helper class using .NET's HTTPClient instead of using RestSharp.